# Serial OperationQueue with Operations synchronizing timer and sleep

Tags: swift, multithreading, concurrency, sleep, operation

I have a serial OperationQueue whose operations call usleep. I do this because the operation execution block synchronizes with a Timer that needs to repeat until a designated time.

For example, 3 operations are added to a queue with a maxconcurrent set to 1. Each operations has a timer that repeats until 10 seconds into the future. Upon firing this timer of the first operation, the next line of code is usleep(10seconds). 10 seconds later the timer completes and the thread wakes up. The next operation begins. This is done by design and works, however, I'm concerns about the implications about a sleeping thread. Is it possible that the thread was handling some other code, context switches to handle the operation, then sleeps for a long time, pausing other executions. Does swift know to let the thread execute other blocks while the operation sleeps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does swift know to let the thread execute other blocks while the operation sleeps?

Maybe it’s just a wording issue, but the thread *is* blocked until the sleep (and subsequent tasks) finish, so it’s not going to be made available to do anything else. But, while the thread is sleeping, the core *can* switch contexts to let some other thread run even though the thread running the operation is tied up.

So using `usleep` (or I might use `Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 10)`) avoids the problem of blocking the core, but it still blocks the thread. And threads are rather limited (e.g. 64 at this point). So, especially if you might have a lot of these operations going on at any given time, thereby risking exhausting the limited threads, I might advise avoid blocking the thread, too. (Then again, if you’re using a `maxConcurrentOperationCount` of 1, as long as you aren’t doing other things that might tie up threads, it probably wouldn’t be too serious of a problem.)

For example, I might define an asynchronous `Operation` subclass, and rather than sleeping, I might just `asyncAfter` (or use a timer) the finishing of the operation to 10 seconds in the future. That way no thread is blocked, either. Or I might consider other patterns to solve the broader problem. It’s hard to say without knowing the broader problem that you’re trying to solve.

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for the thorough response. If Thread A is being used to do some async http request, then on Thread B, a completely different thread, I create the mentioned operation queue and add an operation to it. Is it possible that the core does a context switch on Thread A to execute the operation. Or does it create a entirely new thread through gcd. If the former, couldn’t a long sleep within the operation pause the http request or does the core know Thread A is asleep, and another thread Continues the http task. Thanks a ton from me and my company.

Comment: First, GCD rarely creates new threads. It avails itself of a small pool of “worker threads”, minimizing overhead of spinning up new threads all the time. Every time it needs a thread, it grabs one from that pool (with no guarantee about which one it grabs). Second, a `sleep` on one thread will block its thread, but would not affect the asynchronous request from a separate thread. The only exception would be, for example, the serial queue used by `URLSession`: You’d never want to sleep inside one completion handler or delegate method, as that will block all other `URLSession` delegate methods.

Comment: All of this having been said, I would generally advise ever sleeping in one’s code. It’s a wasteful use of resources. When I see sleep calls, it’s usually code smell of deeper problems. I’d refactor it to eliminate any sleep calls. And if you do that, it completely eliminates certain categories of potential problems. I seriously doubt your sleep on one thread is affecting another (but can’t say without [code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), but just eliminate the sleep call and not only is your code more efficient, but all doubts are eliminated.

Comment: I’m trying to create a pattern of vibrations and delays. I have a list of alternating vibration durations and delays in milliseconds [200,30,100,30]. If a “0” is found in the list, cancel all current vibrates. I have a serial operation queue as described above. Because order of execution matters greatly, I cannot find a solution that works using asyncafter or timer, that doesn’t explode the code complexity. With the new Core Haptic, this is easy, however with older version of iOS, I must handle the pattern myself.